# express js session property undefined

Tags: express, session

I have a few Problem with the session in express.
When i log in i'm setting the session.uid session.user and session.isAuth to its Parameter.
When i click on some other Sides where i need the Info of the Session. It sometimes work, sometimes it doesn't. Sometime i got the Error that 'user' is undefined....
I have this Code. And when i click for Example on editQuestion i got the Error. When i do the console.log in the '/' route it works.
Can someone tell me what i'm missing here?

```
var express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const flush = require("connect-flash");
var path = require("path");
const w2v = require("word2vec");
const port = 3000;
const background = require("./public/js/background.js")
const datahandler = require("./public/js/data_handling.js")
//var routes = require("./routes");

var app = express();

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "public/html"));
//app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    cookie:{maxAge:60000},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "secret"
}));
//app.use(flush());

//Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

const isAuth = (req, res, next)=>{
    if(req.session.isAuth){
        next();
    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}



app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
        res.render("index.html");
});

app.get("/question", function(req,res){
    var Qid = Number(req.query.id)
})

app.get("/search", function(req,res){
    var searchWords = req.query.search.split(' ');
    w2v.loadModel('public/data/word_vectors.txt', (error, model) =>{
        var word_vectors = model.getVectors(searchWords)
        var avg_vector = background.averageVectors(word_vectors, model);
        var questions = background.mostSimilarQuestions('/../data/qentities.txt', avg_vector);
        var resultjson = datahandler.getQuestionsFromSimilar(questions);
        res.json(resultjson)
    })
});

app.get("/search/new", function(req,res){
    
    var resultjson = datahandler.getNewestQuestions();
    //console.log(resultjson);
    res.json(resultjson);
    
});

app.get("/LogIn", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session.user);    
    res.render("LogIn.html");
})
app.post("/logIn",async(req, res) =>{
    //LogIn
    const{username, password} = req.body;
    const user = datahandler.logIn(username, password);
    if(!user){
        return res.send("Log In failed!")
        
    }else{        
        req.session.uid = user[0];
        req.session.user = user[1];
        req.session.isAuth = true;
        req.session.save();
        
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});

app.get("/user",isAuth, (res, req)=>{
    //res.send(req.session.user);
    //res.json(req.session.user)
    res.redirect("Profil.html");//Doesn't work ;(
});

app.get("/editQuestion", isAuth,(res, req)=>{
    //console.log(req.session.user); Not working here. WHY?????
    res.render("editQuestion.html");
});
app.get("/viewQuestion", isAuth,(res, req)=>{
    console.log(req.session.user);
    res.render("viewQuestion.html");
});
app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });    
});

app.get("/Register", function(req,res){
    res.render("Register.html")
})
app.post("/register", async(req,res)=>{
    const{newUsername, password} = req.body;
    const newuser = datahandler.registerNewUser(newUsername, password);
    if(!newuser){
        res.redirect("/Register");
    }
    else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
})

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {

    res.render("about.html");
});


app.all('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(404).render('404.html');
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This is the Out i get when i click on editQuestion:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

And this in the '/' what is correct:

```
TP
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it....
I swapped req and res in the functions...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).